# In sccm 2012 my device collection is not updating

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, sccm-2012

In sccm 2012 my device collection(all system) is not updating properly. When a new computer added to the AD. Sccm also update the same. But if i manually delete any host from AD. Then sccm is not updating its collection.. any idea??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not immediate. Once it's in SCCM, it will stay there until deleted due to inactivity. The time can be changed, and you can also run a report for clients that have not checked in in a long time and manually delete them, or use a powershell script to do this as well.

To summarize, there is a one way sync from AD -> SCCM, the 'discovery' process. It's not an AD mirror in regards to clients.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your Discovery Data deletion task settings in Site Maintenance. I think it's 90 days maximum age by default. You may also want to configure the Inactive Client deletion task settings. Note you don't want to set these very short or your client data will be getting deleted due to relatively brief period of inactivity. At a minimum it must be longer than the heartbeat frequency of the clients.